# Как в qt creator добавить ключ при сборке проекта с помощью CMake

Tags: c++, qtcreator, cmake

Подскажите как пользоваться ключами для сборки в Qt Creator. В самом Cmake файле есть данный код:

`if( BUILD_EXAMPLES ) 
add_subdirectory( examples )
endif()`

Для того что бы собрать проект в консоле я просто выполняю следующую команду :

```
cmake -G"MinGW Makefiles" -DBUILD_EXAMPLES=1 ..
```

Работать с CMake намного удобней в QtCreator но не совсем могу понять как скормить данный ключ. В настройках сборки проекта есть поле CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE в которое был прописан мой ключ но проект не хочет подключать доп директории и не разбирает следующий Cmake файл. Подскажите что я делаю не так.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для простоты и удобства использования cmake в qtCreatore необходимо просто добавить в CMakeFiles следующее:

```
option( NAMEFORKAY "Build examples" off)
```

Данная команда добавить нужный вам ключ во вкладку ключей в настройках сборки в qtCreator. Далее просто в CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE прописываем наш NAMEFORKAY все там же в настройках сборки. И теперь в настройках сборки есть возможность выбирать что вы хотите скомпилировать.